# Discord.py why does it show "None" instead of printing out the NICKNAME of the user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a simple scripts that shows the nickname of someone in the server by pinging them. However it keeps saying None.

```
@client.command()
async def test2(ctx,user:discord.Member):
    print(user.nick)
```

Comment: Maybe the user doesn't have a nick?

Comment: Ah Lukasz long time no see. Thank you. You fixed it

Answer (score 1):

If the user doesn't have a nick it will be `None` - makes sense, if you want to get a name always you can use the `Member.display_name` attribute

```py
print(user.display_name) # Will print the nick if the user has it, otherwise the name
```